# Update new password if the temporary password matches what is on the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, passwords

I have a table and one of the field is `TempPass` which is blank for all users. When user requests to change the password, instead of updating their existing password, my script adds the temporary password which is emailed to the user, to the `TempPass` field using SHA. The following line shows the change:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET TempPass=SHA('$p') WHERE UserID=$uid";
```

I save the password during registration using the following line:

```
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
```

The following if my HTML file:

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStylesScripts/lostPassStyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<title>Reset Password</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

include("mailerClass/class.phpmailer.php");
include("mailerClass/class.smtp.php");

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { // Handle the form.
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) { // Validate the email address.
        $uid = FALSE;
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">You forgot to enter your email address!</font></p>';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['temppass'])) { // Validate the email address.
        $uid = FALSE;
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">You forgot to enter your temporary password!</font></p>';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['newpass'])) { // Validate the email address.
        $uid = FALSE;
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">You forgot to enter your new password!</font></p>';
    }
    else {
        // Check for the existence of that email address.
        $query = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE EmailAddress='".  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "'";
        $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            // Retrieve the user ID.
            list($uid) = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);
        }
        else {
            echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">The submitted email address does not match those on file!</font></p>';
            $uid = FALSE;
        }
    }
    if ($uid) { // If everything’s OK.
        // Make the query.
        $query = "THIS IS THE QUERY THAT WILL COMPARE THE USEREMAIL WITH THE TEMPORARY PASSWORD ASSIGNED AND EMAILED TO WHAT THE USER ENTERED IN THE FORM";
        $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
        if ("USEREMAIL WITH THE AUTO ASSIGNED TEMPORARY PASSWORD MATCHES WITH THE TEMPORARY PASSWORD ENTERED BY THE USER") { // If it ran OK.
            $query = "THIS IS THE QUERY THAT WILL UPDATE THE EXISTING PASSWORD WITH THE NEW PASSWORD ENTERED BY USER";
            $query = "SET TEMPPASS BACK TO NULL FOR THAT USERID";
            echo '<h3>Your password has been changed. You will receive the new, temporary password at the email address with which you registered. Once you have logged in with this password, you may change it by clicking on the "Change Password" link.</h3>';
            mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
            //include (‘./includes/footer.html’); // Include the HTML footer.
            exit();
        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Your password could not be changed due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</font></p>';
        }
    }
    else { // Failed the validation test.
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please try again.</font></p>';
    }
} // End of the main Submit conditional.
?>

<h1>Reset Your Password</h1>

<p>Enter your email address below and your password will be reset.</p>

<form action="resetPass.php" method="post">

<fieldset>

<p><b>Email Address:</b> <input type="email" name="email" size="20" maxlength="40" value="" /></p>
<p><b>Temporary Password:</b> <input type="text" name="temppass" size="20" maxlength="40" value="" /></p>
<p><b>New Password:</b> <input type="text" name="newpass" size="20" maxlength="40" value="" /></p>

</fieldset>

<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create New Password" /></div>

<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I modify the following codes to achieve what I am looking to do:

```
if ($uid) { // If everything’s OK.
    // Make the query.
    $query = "THIS IS THE QUERY THAT WILL COMPARE THE USEREMAIL WITH THE TEMPORARY PASSWORD ASSIGNED AND EMAILED TO WHAT THE USER ENTERED IN THE FORM";
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    if ("USEREMAIL WITH THE AUTO ASSIGNED TEMPORARY PASSWORD MATCHES WITH THE TEMPORARY PASSWORD ENTERED BY THE USER") { // If it ran OK.
        $query = "THIS IS THE QUERY THAT WILL UPDATE THE EXISTING PASSWORD WITH THE NEW PASSWORD ENTERED BY USER";
        $query = "SET TEMPPASS BACK TO NULL FOR THAT USERID";
        echo 'password changed';
        mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
        exit();
    } else { // If it did not run OK.
        echo 'no change. error';
    }
}
```

Also, should I save the new password in `md5` format?

Please note: I will be updating to `mysqli` soon.

Comment: It's not secure to store new passwords in md5, because it has been cracked, use some other hashing like SHA512.

Comment: so replace `MD5` with `SHA512`?

Comment: Here is a tutorial you might find useful : http://www.subinsb.com/2013/08/secure-injection-free-login-system-php.html It also shows how to encrypt passwords with high security ie SHA512.

Comment: For password hashing, use bcrypt, scrypt, or pbkdf2. Also, beware of sql injections, your current code is very vulnerable.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` isn't safe? I use that on all the input from the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($uid) { // If everything’s OK.
    // Make the query.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND TempPass='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['temppass'])."'";
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    if (mysql_row_count($result)==1) { // If it ran OK.
        $query = "UPDATE users SET password=SHA2('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newpass'])."',512) WHERE EmailAddress='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'";
        $query = "UPDATE users SET TempPass='' WHERE EmailAddress='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'";
        echo 'password changed';
        mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
        exit();
    } else { // If it did not run OK.
        echo 'no change. error';
    }
}
```

It's not secure to store new passwords in **MD5**, because it has been [cracked](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-is-cracked-since-1996), use some other hashing like SHA512.

Comment: Should the `*` be `TempPass`?

Comment: It's not needed, because we are only checking for any row counts, nothing Else.

Comment: When retrieving the TempPass and setting the new Password don't I also have to use `SHA` in the SQL statement?

Comment: Can I send you my code? Now it's not working for some reason. It created the account but can't login :/

Comment: Did you change the MD5 function of your SQL code in register page to SHA2 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38628/discussion-between-subin-and-sikni8)